# How do I link to images in WordPress that I've uploaded?

Tags: html, wordpress

I've gathered that I upload the images to `wp-content/uploads`, but once there, how do I link to it in my template files?

If I created a new template after putting, say, `dog.jpg` in that uploads directory, `<img src="dog.jpg" />` does not work - the image doesn't display.

I read `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` should be inserted (I guess?), but putting it before `dog.jpg` in the `src` does not help.

Comment: I can't flesh out a long answer right now  but quick link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link

Comment: that's because bloginfo('template_directory') links to your theme (something like wp-content/themes/yourtheme) and not the uploads folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give full path to the image (with 'http://' and the host), e.g. 'http://myblog.com/wp-content/uploads/dog.jpg'. Or may be give a relative path: "wp-content/uploads/dog.jpg".

Also, as far as I remember, wordpress' upload function puts the images in some subdirectories of  wp-content/uploads based on the date when you have uploaded the image.

Comment: What if it's local? `localhost:8***/wordpress/wp-content/images/dog.jpg`? Or `Users/...`?

Comment: Are sure that dog.jpg actually is in the wordpress/wp-content/images folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading images to the wp-content/uploads directory you should be using the media uploader in the wordpress backend.  Then the file URL is automatically set and given to you for each image.  If you don't want to use the media uploader in wordpress you should be using an image directory in the theme folder, then target those images with:

`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/dog.jpg" />`

Try this and it will work.

Comment: I'm doing it locally, does that matter? I have my wordpress images stored under `wordpress/wp-content/images/dog.jpg`, yet `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/dog.jpg" alt="" />` does not work.

Comment: Put the images in wordpress/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/images and it will work.  You should be storing your images inside your theme directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is for a template in your theme, you should be storing the image along with your theme files. The media uploader is more for your content authors to work with.

If you still desire to reduce repetition (maybe you need to use the image in your content too), then you could hardcode a link to the image as it exists in the uploads folder. But do you really want to risk having a content author delete it and thus break your theme?

Comment: If I just want the image for say, a gallery on the front page, where would be the best place to store the image? I'm gathering that I foolishly assumed files that aren't relevant to the theme specifically (i.e.: simple site images) aren't supposed to be stored alongside theme images.

Comment: Doug follow my post above and it will work.  You can create a new folder in your theme directory if you want to, you don't have to use the theme's images folder.  Just correct the path and it will work.  You could create a new forlder in your theme called "siteimages", and then target the images you put in it with `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/siteimages/dog.jpg" />`if you don't want to store the images along with your theme images.

Comment: I'm doing this locally if it matters. I've made a folder in wp-content/themes/responsive-child/siteimages/ and my image, dog.jpg is in there. I link with the code you've given me, and the image doesn't display (it has the image not found icon). I've installed wordpress at localhost:888/wordpress/, fyi.

Comment: I assume with the path name you listed that you're using a child theme?  That is very relevant information that was omitted in your prior posts.  `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` will get the parent theme directory.  Change it to `<?php get_stylesheet_directory() ?>` and that should work.  So you'd use `<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory() ?>/siteimages/dog.jpg" />`.  Being on a local install should not matter.